# HTML/CSS Textarea and Div are different height

Tags: html, css, textarea

I've styled a textarea with min/max width and min height (to allow scaling vertically, but in no other direction), and put a div next to it with the same height.  For some reason, although the CSS doesn't lie they're different heights.  Anyone know why and if there's a way to fix this other than to adjust the height of either element?

CSS:

```
#textarea {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
#output {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u1c3k072/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most browsers, the `textarea` element has default padding.

In Chrome the element has `2px` of padding on each side, and in IE/FF it has `1px` of padding on each side. You need to remove the padding if you want both elements to have the same height:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/owvrx3yz/)

```
#textarea {
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-height: 200px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

---

You could also change the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model) to include the element's padding/border in the width/height calculations by changing [`box-sizing` to `border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/tk9f0fkm/)

```
#output, #textarea {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I thought I tried that, thanks for the fast response!